# How to import ES module in Tailwind config file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am configuring my own plugins in Tailwind config file by import ES module with CommonJS syntax `require('/my-plugin');` but I get an error when trying to build:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at compileFunction (<anonymous>)
```

Since I am using ES6 statements in the `my-plugin` file (e.g `import`, `export default`) so these causing to throw errors even though I use regular `require` statements to import it in my Tailwind config file.

How do I resolve this problem?

My code:

*tailwind.config.js*

```
const myPlugin = require('./my-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'jit',
    darkMode: 'class',
    content: [
        './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
        './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    ],
    theme: {
    }   
    plugins: [
        myPlugin(),       
    ],
};
```

*./my-plugin*

```
import ... from ...

const MyPlugin = () => {}

export default MyPlugin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you:

- Are running Tailwind v3.3+ for configuration file ESM format support
- Use the `mjs` extension for `tailwind.config.mjs` instead of `tailwind.config.js` if you do not have `"type": "module"` in the project's `package.json`
- Use ESM syntax in the configuration file
- Add a comma after the `theme` object declaration
- Do not execute the `import`ed plugin function

```js
import myPlugin from './my-plugin';

export default {
    mode: 'jit',
    darkMode: 'class',
    content: [
        './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
        './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    ],
    theme: {
    },
    plugins: [
        myPlugin,       
    ],
};
```

Comment: thanks @Wongjin, I have upgrade Tailwind version to latest and it worked.

Comment: "Do not execute the `import`ed plugin function"
Unless one intends to configure the plugin, right?

Comment: Execute the `import`ed plugin function only if it has been constructed via the [`plugin.withOptions()`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#exposing-options) wrapper or similar.